# Why is "The Crying of Lot 49" considered metafiction?

Tags: thomas-pynchon, metafiction, the-crying-of-lot-49

Why is Thomas Pynchon's *The Crying of Lot 49* considered metafiction?

I've read some articles about historiographic metafiction in *The Crying of Lot 49*, but still can't understand it.

- Rabeb Ben Hania: ["The historiographic metafictional writing of power and the power of writing historiographic metafiction in Thomas Pynchon’s The Crying of Lot 49"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290448033_The_historiographic_metafictional_writing_of_power_and_the_power_of_writing_historiographic_metafiction_in_Thomas_Pynchon%27s_The_Crying_of_Lot_49), Conference: International Conference on Power and Counter-power (Tunis, Tunsia, 2014).
- Francisco Collado-Rodriguez: ["Historiographic Metafiction, Thermodynamics and the Middle That Was Not Excluded in Thomas Pynchon’s The Crying of 49" (PDF)](http://typh.unizar.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/5-Francisco-Collado-Rodriguez_Historiographic-Metafiction-Crying.pdf), in *Metahistorical Narratives & Scientific Metafictions*, edited by Giuseppe Episcopo (Naples: Cronopio, 2015).

I guess the metafictional nature of *The Crying of Lot 49* is due to Pynchon's awareness of some historical / scientific process, and not to direct metafiction devices in his work. Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to issue a frame challenge in answer to this one: *The Crying of Lot 49* is not, generally, considered historiographic metafiction, and essays that suggest otherwise are misusing the term.

The reason for this is simple. Wikipedia gives the following definition of [historiographic metafiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historiographic_metafiction):

> works of fiction which combine the literary devices of metafiction with historical fiction.

*The Crying of Lot 49* was written in 1966. While no definitive date for the action of the novel is given, it is strongly implied to be the mid 60s. We can infer this not only from the general tone, dates (Bortz talks about 1957 as being in the recent past) and cultural markers given, but from the inclusion of the pop band The Paranoids, who are clearly a Beatles stand-in.

So: if a novel written in 1966 is set only a few years before, it cannot, by definition, qualify as "historical fiction". By extension, therefore, it also cannot qualify as "historiographic metafiction". Having looked at the papers you've linked, I would suggest they're fairly low quality stuff, full of buzzwords and deliberate obscurantism rather than anything particularly revealing. My feeling is that the authors treated "historiographic metafiction" as another buzz-phrase to cross off their academic bingo cards.

That said, I can see some honest reasons for such an error. *The Crying of Lot 49* certainly does qualify as metafiction, for one thing. The presence of a book within a book - The Courier's Tragedy - is a key plot device that takes up a significant amount of the text. The character's reactions to his fictional play, particularly around the analysis of its various different published versions, mirror exactly the kind of academic deconstruction Pynchon is expecting his readers to perform on his book.

Furthermore, the definition of historiographic metafiction given on Wikipedia continues:

> Works regarded as historiographic metafiction are also distinguished by frequent allusions to other artistic, historical and literary texts.

And again, *The Crying of Lot 49* abounds in such references. We've already mentioned The Paranoids standing in for The Beatles, but the book also alludes to *Lolita* (it's likely that Pynchon attended Nabokov's lectures as a student), Spanish surrealist painter Remedios Varo, various mythological or divine figures including Oedipus and Saint Narcissus and so on.

So, given that the novel does cleave quite closely to the requirements for historiographic metafiction, it's perhaps understandable that people might mistake it for such. But in the strictest sense it can't be, because it's neither historical nor historiographic.

Comment: "Another buzz-phrase to cross off their academic bingo cards." This answer is worth an upvote just for that phrase.